# Multipage for using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I took over a project and I'm trying to correct existing code.  I am unable to show code because of confidentiality, but I will try to ask my question with as much detail as I can, and if absolutely necessary I will try to show the code that I think I'm working with.

Now this form uses a bunch of js files.  The form itself uses javascript and ajax calling php files when needed.  This gives the form an illusion of being multipage, but in fact it is only one.  So the first 'page' has fields to fill in and when the user clicks next it replaces that 'page' with the next 'page' and so on. On one page is a list of checkboxes, picking one of the checkboxes sets a variable to that value.  Then later in the form it is called and displayed.

So going through the form 'pages' there are next and go back buttons which uses javascript to simply replace the current 'page' with the next 'page' but since it is technically all the same page all of the form fields are staying filled in until the last 'page' where it is entered into the database.

So if a user picks one of the check boxes and goes to the page that displays that value, then clicks back to the checkbox page and selects a different one, when they go back through the form the previous checkbox value is displayed not the new value from the change.  How can I get it to change to the new value.  Everything else works, if the checkbox is changed and the form is saved to the database the change will be saved, but it just doesn't display the correct data from the change.

There are several spots where I need this to change, but I don't want to lose the data from all fields just when the user changes certain things it will change everywhere in the form.

If code is needed I can post simple lines, but I can't give full code.

Thanks.

[UPDATE]

```
    //The below code is in the form data javascript file.
    //validate//
    var field  = findField(page, 'data');
         //Above is setting the data for the field Below is getting the checkbox value from the previous 'page'.
    var checks = findField(form.check[0], 'check').value.split(/\s*\,\s*/);
    for (var i in checks) {
    var checkbox_id = checks[i];
    var check    = checkdata('check')[checkbox_id];
    //Removed project detail
    info += '<p>For ' + check.name + ' displayed:</p>';
```

Okay, above is a bit of where it is being displayed.  I've narrowed down the problem to what is being displayed is not being cleared on the back button.  So the check.name is being displayed until the field that forces it to display is changed, then the check.name will change to the correct value.  So when the 'page' is cycling, is there javascript that I can use to just clear out that field when the user clicks the back button.  Could it be that simple?  I hope the above code helps a bit.

Comment: If company rules don't allow you to post the actual code how about creating a smaller sample proof of concept that demonstrates the issue you are having? We can help with that and then you can apply our advice back to your real code. (I realise this may take some effort on your part, but otherwise you're basically asking us to implement the whole thing from scratch for you just so that we can effectively indicate how to do what you're asking. And we may guess wrong on what you mean in which case everybody's time was wasted...)

Comment: I am afraid only describing the problem is insufficient; we need something concrete to look at, in order to give you a useful answer.

Comment: I updated my question with some sample code.

Comment: When you talk about the "back button" are you talking about your own button in your page or the browser's back button?

Comment: Itis a button in the page that will remove the current displaying 'page' and replace it with the 'page' that comes before it.  If the user uses the browser's back button it clears out everything and they have to start over.

Comment: @user2993209 - then you need to read my answer below and figure out which of those two cases is happening.  It pretty much has to be one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this.

What I did was went to where the output is and took the code that stored it to a variable.  Since this is all one file, when the user clicks 'Go Back' the variable is still set.  So when the user goes back to change the earlier field I put in code that checks to see if the variable is empty.  If it is it does nothing, if it is not then it will set the variable to nothing, so it will again be set later on in the code with the updated data.

Easy Peasy.  I don't understand the confusion.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Without code, we can only guess, but here are some possible guesses:

If the DOM elements from the prior form elements are being saved (not being destroyed and then recreated when someone goes to the next form and then comes back), then the DOM elements will retain their previous values unless some of your code is changing those values.  So, if the DOM elements are being preserved and the values of the checkboxes are changing, then it has to be because some of your code is changing them.  The most likely guess would be that there is some code that is attempting to initialize the checkboxes to the initial value from before any editing was done.  If that's the case, then you need to make sure this code is NOT run when a page is being displayed that has already been shown to the user and edited.

If the DOM elements are being destroyed and recreated when navigating from form to form, then the current value of these checkboxes needs to be saved in a javascript variable somewhere so when the user navigates back to a prior form the checkboxes can be create and initialized, not from the database, but from the previous edited values.

Comment: I updated my question.  It's just an issue with the user filling in the field and the checkbox data displaying, it is already displayed and stays showing when the user goes back to the previous 'page' and changes the checkbox.  It's like this form is one page and the user scrolls down and the checkbox data displays.  Then they scroll up and change the checkbox, when they scroll back down it'll still show the previous data, until changed.  I hate dealing with other people's code.  Especially when it's not commented.

Comment: @user2993209 - checkboxes don't spontaneously change their values.  The checkbox is either getting destroyed and then recreated and not populated with the former value or there is code that is resetting the value - just like I said in my answer.  You need to figure out which it is.  Since you aren't sharing the actual code, we can't show you which it is.

Comment: The problem is not with the checkbox.  It is with the field that displays the checkbox data.  The form is one javascript page that when the user clicks the next box the javascript replaces the displaying page with the next page, but it is still the same file.  So the display is always there because it was already set and displayed.  If I change th checkbox then go to the displaying section it will show previous data because it was already showing in the section it was just hidden behind the other section.  If I change the data that displays it in the form the correct data displays.

Comment: So if I add code to the checkbox that sets the later field to nothing so when the user goes back to that page they would have to reset it for the correct data to display.    Let me try that.

Comment: @user2993209 - you've lost me completely.  Your question refers to a checkbox value being wrong and now you say it isn't the checkbox at all.  I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I updated my question and I said that selecting one of the checkboxes will display that data on one of the following pages when that specific field is set by the user.  When the field is set and the data is displayed and then the user goes back and changes the checkbox data and then returns to the displaying page, the old data will display because it was already there on the page.  If the field is edited, then the correct data will display.  I am now trying to figure out how to clear that field so nothing will display until the user sets the field again and then the correct data will display

Comment: @user2993209 - we really can't help you without seeing the code.

Comment: Okay, I think all I really need is the JavaScript code to clear fields.  So user clicks check box for male, goes through form gets to the profile where the message You are male appears after the user enters their birthday.  So they go back to the check box and click female, deselects male and then proceeds through form.  Currently it would show male until the birthday is changed which would then check the value of gender.  What I am trying to do is when the check box is selected or deselected it would clear the birth date field.

Answer (score 0):

Save all data to some array/object. When you return to some page, fill in selected checkboxes and then reset status of all those checkboxes to default and when user submits that part of form, it will assign them again.